# Can a WP $post object be output as REST-API-formatted JSON from a theme file?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a `Backbone.js` site that uses `WordPress` as a CMS. The `Backbone` app is configured to consume JSON from the WP REST API. I'd like to bootstrap the post JSON for the initial page load by outputting it from the WP theme. What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
$postsJSON = [];
$restResponse = new WP_REST_Response();
$restRequest = new WP_REST_Request();
while (have_posts()) { the_post();
  $postsJSON[] = apply_filters('rest_prepare_post', $restResponse, $post, $restRequest);
}
echo "<script type='application/json'>[" . join(",", $postsJSON) . "</script>";
```

But this code does not work. I just get an empty `WP_REST_Response`. Is there an easier way to convert the `$post` object to REST-API-formatted JSON?

Answer (score 3):

I figured this one out. There is still room for improvement with this method but it is working well enough for me now:

```
<?php
$postsJSON = [];
$restControllers = [];
$restRequest = new WP_REST_Request();
while (have_posts()) { the_post();
    if (!isset($restControllers[$post->post_type])) {
        $restControllers[$post->post_type] = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller($post->post_type);
    }

    $preparedPost = $restControllers[$post->post_type]->prepare_item_for_response($post, $restRequest);
    $postsJSON[] = json_encode($preparedPost->data);
}
?>
<script id="data-posts" type="application/json">
  [<?php echo join(",", $postsJSON); ?>]
</script>
```

Potential concerns with this approach:

1. May need to use a different `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` in some cases.
2. Using an empty instance of `WP_REST_Request` may have unintended consequences.